StringLike condition in AWS S3 policy
I'm trying to set up aws policy on a s3 bucket that has following structure:
s3://my-bucket/source-name/raw
s3://my-bucket/source-name/processed
s3://my-bucket/source-name/curated

Only part of the path that will change is source-name. I want to set up my policy so that third party tool can access only to curated folder for every source. I tried following policy but the StringLike seems like doesn't work this way.
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectVersion",
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowOnlyCuratedFolder",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "s3:prefix": "curated"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}

Anyone has an idea how to set up this?
